# PHP POST variables using link with get variable

Tags: php, http-post

i want to POST variable using following url example:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?p=1">
    <input id="mail" type="text" size="50" placeholder="E-Mail" />
    <input id="password" type="password" size="50" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

With the p-Variable in the link my site determine which default site should be shown.

My problem is that no data is available in the $_POST array in my default site.

Is it possible that the $_POST-data is only available for the next script that is called?

Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Try with `name` attribute

Comment: Basic HTML can be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the inputs. For example `name="mail"`:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?p=1">
    <input name="mail" id="mail" type="text" size="50" placeholder="E-Mail" />
```

Then you would access `$_GET['p']` and `$_POST['mail']`.